# Dealing with "Malformated" Arrays

Tags: c#, api, json.net, matomo

Currently, I am trying to parse results from the Piwik API to a List of C# objects. However, the way the Json is formatted is not really allowing me to do this.

I am getting the following data from the Piwik API (sample data):

```
{   "2012-05-27" : [  ],
    "2012-05-28" : [  ],
    "2012-05-29" : { "avg_time_on_site" : 309,
      "bounce_count" : 1,
      "bounce_rate" : "33%",
      "max_actions" : 36,
      "nb_actions" : 72,
      "nb_actions_per_visit" : 24,
      "nb_uniq_visitors" : 2,
      "nb_visits" : 3,
      "sum_visit_length" : 928
},
    "2012-05-30" : { "avg_time_on_site" : 263,
      "bounce_rate" : "0%",
      "max_actions" : 37,
      "nb_actions" : 70,
      "nb_actions_per_visit" : 23.300000000000001,
      "nb_uniq_visitors" : 3,
      "nb_visits" : 3,
      "sum_visit_length" : 788
  }
}
```

Now, I created a "VisitsSummary" type to which I want to cast the Jason "within" each date:

```
   public class VisitsSummaryResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("nb_uniq_visitors")]
        public int NumUniqueVisitors { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nb_visits")]
        public int NumVisits { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nb_actions")]
        public int NumActions { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nb_visits_converted")]
        public int NumVisitsConverted { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("bounce_count")]
        public int BounceCount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sum_visit_length")]
        public int SumVisitLength { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("max_actions")]
        public int MaxActions { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("bounce_rate")]
        public string BounceRate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nb_actions_per_visit")]
        public double NumActionsPerVisit { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("avg_time_on_site")]
        public int AverageTimeOnSite { get; set; }
    }
```

However, since the data is formatted by using the dates in the array, I cannot get Json.NET to understand that it should treat it as an array. Does that make sense?

Additionally, it would be nice to automatically tell Json.NET to parse the date *into* a property of the VisitsSummaryResult - is this somehow possible? Then I could add "VisitsSummaryResult.Date" to the class to nicely wrap it all into one object.

Currently, I can only think of *pre-parsing* the Json myself and then passing the individual Json snippets to Json.NET for the conversion to C# objects - but that's less than optimal.

Would anyone have a pointer as to how to solve this issue?

¡Gracias!

**EDIT:** I also tried it with a generic dictionary to get Key->Value (Date->VisitsSummaryResult), but to no avail.

```
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, VisitsSummaryResult>>(e.Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems as if the problem is due to the fact that there are some empty entries in the Json array, which throws off the deserialisation.

So, the only way I could solve this, is the following (dirty) solution to deserialise empty arrays to null and everything else to my own type:

```
        Dictionary<string, VisitsSummaryResult> myObjList = new Dictionary<string, VisitsSummaryResult>();
        Dictionary<string, object> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(e.Result);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
        {
            try
            {
                myObjList.Add(pair.Key, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VisitsSummaryResult>(pair.Value.ToString())); // Getting the raw, inner Json string
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                myObjList.Add(pair.Key, null); // Exception: insert null
            }
        }
```

If anyone has a cleaner solution on how to deal with empty arrays in Json.NET, I'd really appreciate that.

¡Gracias!